# How do I make Distribute Points on Faces Geometry use weight pain vertex group?

Tags: geometry-nodes, weight-painting, vertex-groups

I have a vertex group made using the Weight Paint and I am using a Geometry Node to distribute an object across the plane. How do I make the Geometry Node use the vertex group to distribute the objects?

[image: description]

The idea is that there will be fewer objects on the lighter parts and more on the red areas so I how would I connect them?

Comment: You just have to plug a Named Attribute with the name of your group...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this:

[image]

Important is the input value of the group input as float value, put/choose the name of your vertex group in the modifier. Plug your input value in the density (you often need a multiply because vertex just has value from 0 to 1)

Comment: Hi Chris I can't get it to work https://snipboard.io/Ng4WSi.jpg What did I do wrong? It's still showing in the blue area with same density as the red area.

Comment: Thanks, @Harry McKenzie works if put Named Attribute Node for input of multiply and select vertex group

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie: if you provide your blend file and it is a serious question, i will take a look. Contact data in my profile if you don't wanna provide it here.