GN output render eevee different than viewport

I put some flowers on a bean stock using Geometry Notes.
But the flowers in the render are in different places then in the viewport.
How can I fix this?
Second question:
Is there a way to use weight paint to prevent the flowers to be in certain spots?
Screen shot:

Render:



Please don't ask more than one question for each question you post. For your second one, try the answer here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/282854/how-do-i-make-distribute-points-on-faces-geometry-use-weight-pain-vertex-group. There are also several YT videos detailing the same method.

Weight paint doesn't seem to work because the trunks of the bean stock are curves, not a mesh.

Do you have subdivision modifier on the object? Subdivision modifier has a separate setting for rendering and viewport, which will make the geometry different and cause the random distribution of flowers to be different in viewport and render. There are other modifiers that have similar settings for viewport and rendering, so check if that's the case.

Yes! It was the subdivison.
